# Looping through list of columns

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a large data frame, one column shows the province where the respondent is coming from. I would like to see differences of values between respondents from provinces in some columns, based on column name (e.g. for the columns Hope, Responsibility, Efficacy).

```
Province  Hope  Responsibility  Efficacy Age
   A       4         3            2      24
   A       2         1            4      23
   C       5         3            5      20
   B       3         2            3      29
   A       1         1            4      23
   B       3         3            2      25
```

So far I looped through differences between all combinations of provinces for each column:

```
list1 = list('A', 'B', 'C', 'D' 'E', 'F')
list2 = list('B', 'C', 'D' 'E', 'F')

for (i in list1){
  for (j in list2){
    t <- t.test(dt[Province == i, Hope], dt[Province == j, Hope])
    if (t$p.value <= 0.05){
      print(paste("Results:",i,"and",j))
      print(t)
    }}}
```

How can I create a loop that loops through a list of columns based on the column name, e.g. something like this (which does not work).

**THIS PART IS EDITED**

```
list1 = list('A', 'B', 'C', 'D' 'E', 'F')
list2 = list('B', 'C', 'D' 'E', 'F')
list3 = list('Hope', 'Responsibility', 'Efficacy')

for (c in list3){
  for (i in list1){
    for (j in list2){
      t <- t.test(dt[Province == i, c], dt[Province == j, c])
      if (t$p.value <= 0.05){
        print(paste("Results:",i,"and",j))
        print(t)
      }}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get `unique` values of `Province` and use `lapply` to iterate over the column names of `dt` and use `outer` to get p-values of `t.test` for every combination.

```
list1 <- unique(dt$Province)

apply_t_test <- function(x, y, col) {
        t.test(dt[dt$Province == x, col], dt[dt$Province == y, col])$p.value
}
apply_t_test <- Vectorize(apply_t_test)
cols <- c('Hope', 'Responsibility', 'Efficacy')

result <- sapply(cols, function(column) outer(list1, list1, function(x, y) 
               apply_t_test(x, y, column)), simplify = FALSE)
```

The `result` would look something like this :

```
#$Hope
#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] 1.00000000 0.01146182 0.77720749
#[2,] 0.01146182 1.00000000 0.02880269
#[3,] 0.77720749 0.02880269 1.00000000

#$Responsibility
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] 1.0000000 0.8624039 0.5206825
#[2,] 0.8624039 1.0000000 0.3795635
#[3,] 0.5206825 0.3795635 1.0000000

#$Efficacy
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] 1.0000000 0.6411564 0.5822007
#[2,] 0.6411564 1.0000000 0.9467599
#[3,] 0.5822007 0.9467599 1.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the data table contains way more columns and I would only like to run t-tests for specific columns based on their column name.

Comment: @MacOS OP's data is insufficient to get meaningful results. You need to generate some fake  data to get `result`.

Comment: @Schoguan You can run this for specific columns as well. You can select columns by names, or pattern in their names or column numbers etc. On which columns do you want to run t.test on?

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks for pointing that out! I missed that. However, this is then not a mimum viable example.

Comment: @RonakShah thank you! In this example, I want to test it for Hope, Responsibility and Efficacy, but not Age (or any subsequent columns that I did not add in this example)

Comment: You can pass those column names in `sapply`. See updated answer.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you! I tried it but am receiving this error message: "Error in `[.data.table`(dt, dt$F15 == x, col) : j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'col' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..col]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1."

Comment: Seems like you have `data.table`, can you run this first `setDF(dt)` to change it to dataframe and try the above again?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to achieve, I'm sorry. However, there are two errors in your code and logic, as far as I can see.

First, how you select rows and columns

```r
dt[Province == i, Hope]
```

This can only work if you have defined `Province` somewhere. However, based on your logic, it seems that this does not make sense since you want to select rows of `dt`. The same is true for `Hope`. If you want to select column `Hope`, you need to pass in a character. This leads to the following code.

```r
dt[dt$Province == i, "Hope"]
```

That said, I think what you really wanted is

```r
dt[dt$Province == i, c]
```

because you have defined list `list3` and loop over it, but you don't use it.

Second, your call to `t.test`. Based on the observations above, we have

```r
t.test(dt[dt$Province == i, c], dt[dt$Province == j, c])
```

This can not work, because this produces vectors of different lengths. For example, in the first loop of the loops you would have

```
dt[dt$Province == "A", "Hope"] = (4, 2, 1)
dt[dt$Province == "B", "Hope"] = (3, 3)
```

And this can not work because `t.test` assumes two vectors of equal length.

I hope this helps. Also, check out @Ronak Shah answer.

Comment: Thanks!
I indeed had a mistake in the example and edited in the original post above (regarding not looping through list 3).
Regarding "Province" -> this is the name of the column and works for me in the first block of code that I posted.